# Data array not send in email

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, dynamic

I have a table that allows to add, edit and delete rows.

I want to send all rows to the email, but only send the last row.

Test with different codes but it didn't work.

*HTML code for table.*

encomenda.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Referência</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Preço (€)</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" for="produto" name="produto[item1]" id="produto" placeholder="Exemplo*" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" for="referencia" name="referencia[item2]" id="referencia" placeholder="#00000"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" for="quantidade" name="quantidade[item3]"  id="quantidade" placeholder="10*" ></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" for="preco" name="preco[item4]" id="preco" placeholder="10.0004"></td>
            <td>
                <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script code for add, edit and delete rows.

javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    $(".add-new").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" for="produto" name="produto[item1]" id="produto" placeholder="Exemplo*" ></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" for="referencia" name="referencia[item2]" id="referencia" placeholder="#00000"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" class="form-control" for="quantidade" name="quantidade[item3]" id="quantidade" placeholder="10*" ></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" class="form-control" for="preco" name="preco[item4]" id="preco" placeholder="10.0004"></td>' +
        '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".add", function () {
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="number"]');
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');

        input.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if (!empty) {
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function () {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

*PHP code to send data to email.*

**email.php**

```
<?php
$item1 = $_POST['produto']['item1'];
$item2 = $_POST['referencia']['item2'];
$item3 = $_POST['quantidade']['item3'];
$item4 = $_POST['preco']['item4'];

$to = "email@email.pt";
$remetente = "email@email.pt";
 
$boundary = date("d-m-Y");
$headers.= "Form - ";
$headers.= "$boundary\n"; 


$corpo_mensagem = "


Product: $item1 
Ref.: $item2
Qtd: $item3
Price: $item4 €


$mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; 
$mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
$mensagem.= "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something";
$mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n";
}?>
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same `name` in every row of the table for each of the inputs. The browser can only transmit one value for each name.

Write the input names like this:

```
produto[]
```

(so without the "item1", "item2" etc in the brackets), so that it forms an array without specific indexes.

Then in the PHP you'd have to loop through them to get each individual value

e.g. as a very simple example:

```
foreach ($_POST['produto'] as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```